# Vulkan proper frame synchronization

Tags: c++, linux, gpu, vulkan

I'm [trying to synchronize frames](https://github.com/bilek993/CLUSEK-RT/blob/master/engine/ecs/systems/RenderSystem.cpp#L348) in Vulkan API, but I have some weird problems. I implemented synchronization like this:

```
void RenderSystem::OnUpdate(const float deltaTime)
{
    uint32_t frameIndex{};

    auto result = SwapChain->AcquireNextImageIndex(PresentationCompleteSemaphore.get(),
                                                   nullptr,
                                                   &frameIndex);

    InFlightFences[frameIndex]->Wait();
    InFlightFences[frameIndex]->Reset();

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR)
    {
        Recreate();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error when acquiring next image...");
    }

    UpdateModelMatrix(deltaTime, frameIndex); // TODO: Remove this! For testing purposes only

    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    GraphicsMainQueue.Submit({ TriangleCommandBuffers[frameIndex].get() },
                             { PresentationCompleteSemaphore.get() },
                             { RenderCompleteSemaphore.get() },
                             InFlightFences[frameIndex].get(),
                             waitStages);

    result = PresentationQueue.Present({ RenderCompleteSemaphore.get() },
                                       { SwapChain.get() },
                                       &frameIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || MainWindow->HasBeenResized())
        Recreate();
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to present result!");
}
```

And it works on Windows 10 like a charm. Unfortunately on Linux Mint, it doesn't work in some cases. First of all, moving window on Linux is very laggy and sometimes freezes the whole OS for a second, but it's not the biggest problem. Closing the window calls `vkDeviceWaitIdle` and... it freezes the application. It will never start responding because it will wait for the device forever. The validation layer doesn't report any problem with my code.

I partly solved this problem by moving fences synchronization at the bottom of my function, but in my opinion, it's a suboptimal solution, because I wait for the frame to finish rendering, instead of preparing the next frame.

```
    // ...

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || MainWindow->HasBeenResized())
        Recreate();
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to present result!");

    InFlightFences[frameIndex]->Wait();
    InFlightFences[frameIndex]->Reset();
}
```

How can I properly synchronize frames not only on Windows but also on Linux? What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one set of semaphores. That means access to those semaphores might be missynchronized.

Let's see the code without the distractors:

```
AcquireNextImageIndex( PresentationCompleteSemaphore, frameIndex );
InFlightFences[frameIndex].WaitAndReset();
QSubmit( PresentationCompleteSemaphore, RenderCompleteSemaphore, InFlightFences[frameIndex] );
Present( RenderCompleteSemaphore, frameIndex );
```

Now, how do we know we can reuse the `PresentationCompleteSemaphore` on `AcquireNextImageIndex()`?

The `QSubmit` waits\unsignals it, and must then finish. We could infer it finished from the fence passed to `QSubmit`, but the fence wait happens only after the `AcquireNextImageIndex()`. So the semaphore still might be in use while `AcquireNextImageIndex()` tries to reuse it. This is a possible program flow:

```
AcquireNextImageIndex( PresentationCompleteSemaphore ) -> frameIndex = 0;
InFlightFences[0].WaitAndReset();
QSubmit( PresentationCompleteSemaphore, RenderCompleteSemaphore, InFlightFences[0] );

// hazard; QSubmit still might be waiting on PresentationCompleteSemaphore
AcquireNextImageIndex( PresentationCompleteSemaphore ) -> frameIndex = 1;
InFlightFences[1].WaitAndReset();
```

How do we know we can reuse the `RenderCompleteSemaphore`?

The `QSubmit` can only use it when `Present()` is already done with it. Only sane way historically to infer this is when `AcquireNextImageIndex()` gives back the same swapchain image. This is a possible program flow:

```
AcquireNextImageIndex( PresentationCompleteSemaphore ) -> frameIndex = 0;
QSubmit( PresentationCompleteSemaphore, RenderCompleteSemaphore, InFlightFences[0] );
Present( RenderCompleteSemaphore, 0 );

AcquireNextImageIndex( PresentationCompleteSemaphore ) -> frameIndex = 1;
// hazard; RenderCompleteSemaphore might still be waited on by Present
// which presented image 0, but we acquired image 1, so it might be async
QSubmit( PresentationCompleteSemaphore, RenderCompleteSemaphore, InFlightFences[1] );
```

So one way to deal with this properly can be [like so](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/blob/343dfc4253f95eed3fc8d268e8f59426b088112a/doc/Schema.pdf):
[image]

That translates to code something like this:

```
InFlightFences[frame].WaitAndReset();
// AcquiredSemaphore[frame] safe to (re)use from here on
AcquireNextImageIndex( AcquiredSemaphore[frame], imageIndex );
// We know that present should be done with swapchainImage[imageIndex]
// after AcquiredSemaphore[frame] is signaled,
// so RenderedSemaphore[imageIndex] should be safe to (re)use afterwards
QSubmit( AcquiredSemaphore[frame], RenderedSemaphore[imageIndex], InFlightFences[frame] );
Present( RenderedSemaphore[imageIndex], frame );
frame = (frame + 1) % 2;
```

Now there are also some new extension ways to deal with it. `VK_KHR_present_wait` extension offers a way to determine if image was presented to the user, and `VK_EXT_swapchain_maintenance1` adds a fence to `vkQueuePresentKHR()`.